# How to insert data after a PayPal payment with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, eloquent, paypal-rest-sdk

I am implementing payments with paypal and everything is correct, however I would like to make when the payment is successful insert in my table users, data in my column "hours" and save data of transaction, I am trying to pass in the form an input with the value of the corresponding hours depending of the plan, however when making a request does not bring that data. I am using "paypal / rest-api-sdk-php: *"

view:

```
<form class="w3-container w3-display-middle w3-card-4 w3-padding-16" method="POST" id="payment-form"
      action="{!! URL::to('paypal') !!}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" id="hours" type="text" name="hours" value="13" style="display: none;">
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" id="amount" type="text" name="amount" value="199" style="display: none;">
    <button href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary text-uppercase">Pagar con Paypal</button>
</form>
```

PaymentController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
/** All Paypal Details class **/
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use URL;
use App\User;
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    private $_api_context;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        /** PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $paypal_conf['client_id'],
                $paypal_conf['secret'])
        );
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('paywithpaypal');
    }
    public function payWithpaypal(Request $request)
    {

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName('Item 1') /** item name **/
        ->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice($request->get('amount')); /** unit price **/
        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));
        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($request->get('amount'));
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Your transaction description');
        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::to('status')) /** Specify return URL **/
        ->setCancelUrl(URL::to('status'));
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        /** dd($payment->create($this->_api_context));exit; **/
        try {
            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
                \Session::put('error', 'Connection timeout');
                return Redirect::to('/');
            } else {
                \Session::put('error', 'Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
        }
        foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }
        /** add payment ID to session **/
        Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());
        if (isset($redirect_url)) {
            /** redirect to paypal **/
            return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }
        \Session::put('error', 'Unknown error occurred');
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    public function getPaymentStatus(Request $request)
    {

        **$hours = $request->get('hours');
        dd($hours);
        //output NULL**

        /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
        $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
        /** clear the session payment ID **/
        Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
        if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
            \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
        $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
        $execution = new PaymentExecution();
        $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));
        /**Execute the payment **/
        $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
            **/* HERE I WANT TO INSERT WHEN PAYMENT IS APPROVED */**
//            \Session::put('success', 'Payment success, hours added to your account');
//            return Redirect::to('/planes');
        }
        \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that `payWithpaypal()` is the method which handles the POST to `URL::to('paypal')`, and that the pingback/webhook from Paypal will hit your `getPaymentStatus()` method? If yes, then the `$request` in `getPaymentStatus()` comes from Paypal, not your form, and it will not include the fields you added on the form.  I think a better approach is to create a placeholder record in your database in `payWithpaypal()`, with a field like `status` set to `pending`, and saving your `hours` value there. Then in `getPaymentStatus()` you retrieve that record, and update `status`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use session to store that data or local storage or you can save that in item list
or you can do is treat hours as product and use cart system

but item list is good option